# Aggregate parents recursively in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, recursion, parent-child, aggregate-functions

In a child-parent table, I need to aggregate all parents for each child. I can readily get children per parent in a CTE query, but can't figure how to reverse it ([sqfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb52c/1)). Given this:

```
CREATE TABLE rel(
  child integer,
  parent integer
);

INSERT INTO rel(child, parent)
VALUES
(1,NULL),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,3),
(5,2),
(6,4),
(7,2),
(8,7),
(9,8);
```

a query that will return an array of parents (order is not important):

```
1, {NULL}
2, {1}
3, {1}
4, {3,1}
5, {2,1}
6, {4,3,1}
7, {2,1}
8, {7,2,1}
9, {8,7,2,1}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if there is an accepted answer, I would like to show how the problem can be solved in pure SQL in a much simpler way, with a *recursive CTE:*

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(child, parentlist) AS (
  SELECT child , ARRAY[]::INTEGER[] FROM rel WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT rel.child, rel.parent || t.parentlist 
    FROM rel 
    JOIN t ON rel.parent = t.child
) SELECT * FROM t;


 child | parentlist 
-------+------------
     1 | {}
     2 | {1}
     3 | {1}
     4 | {3,1}
     5 | {2,1}
     7 | {2,1}
     6 | {4,3,1}
     8 | {7,2,1}
     9 | {8,7,2,1}
(9 rows)
```

If you insist on having a singleton `{NULL}` for children with an empty list of parents, just say

```
SELECT child,
       CASE WHEN CARDINALITY(parentlist) = 0 
            THEN ARRAY[NULL]::INTEGER[]
            ELSE parentlist
       END
  FROM t;
```

instead of `SELECT * FROM t`, but frankly, I don’t see why you should.

A final remark: I am not aware of any efficient way to do this with relational databases, either in pure SQL or with procedural languages. The point is that `JOIN`’s are inherently expensive, and if you have really large tables, your queries will take lots of time. You can mitigate the problem with indexes, but the best way to tackle this kind of problems is by using graphing software and not RDBMS.

Comment: I accepted the first answer because it works, but that of @Dario is far simpler, so I will switch the accept; no idea if that's 'proper' on SO, but makes sense. The harder problem I have is running this against a child-parent table with 2.5 million rows! Will update if/when it finishes.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a general final remark. It is always unpleasant to unaccept a perfectly legitimate, correct answer. The best practice to avoid such a situation is to wait 24/48 hours before accepting an answer, to give users from all timezones of the planet their chance.

Comment: If you just need to query the ancestors of one child, the functions is far more fast because only generates the ancestors for one child. The query generates the ancestors for all the rows and then you can query for one child (unless there's a way to recursively generate the ancestors for only one child, is more processing). To be even faster, you can create a column or table `ancestors` and insert the result of the recursive query; that would be the fastest solution to query.

Answer (score 2):

For this you *can create a PL. I did something similar, here is my PL that handles any father-son structure, it returned a table, but for your case I changed a little bit:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ancestors(text,integer,integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ancestors(
    table_name text,
    son_id integer,-- the id of the son you want its ancestors
    ancestors integer)-- how many ancestors you want. 0 for every ancestor.
RETURNS integer[]
AS $$
DECLARE
    ancestors_list integer[];
    father_id integer:=0;
    query text;
    row integer:=0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        query:='SELECT child, parent FROM '||quote_ident(table_name) || ' WHERE child='||son_id;
        EXECUTE query INTO son_id,father_id;
        RAISE NOTICE 'son:% | father: %',son_id,father_id;
        IF son_id IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            ancestors_list:=array_append(ancestors_list,father_id);
            son_id:=father_id;
        ELSE
            ancestors:=0;
            father_id:=0;
        END IF;
        IF ancestors=0
        THEN
            EXIT WHEN father_id IS NULL;
        ELSE
            row:=row+1;
            EXIT WHEN ancestors<=row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ancestors_list;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Once the PL is created, to get wat you want just query:

```
SELECT *,ancestors('rel',child,0) from rel
```

This returns:

```
child | parent | ancestors
------+--------+-----------------
1     | NULL   | {NULL}
2     | 1      | {1,NULL}
3     | 1      | {1,NULL}
4     | 3      | {3,1,NULL}
5     | 2      | {2,1,NULL}
6     | 4      | {4,3,1,NULL}
7     | 2      | {2,1,NULL}
8     | 7      | {7,2,1,NULL}
9     | 8      | {8,7,2,1,NULL}
```

If you don't want the NULL to appear, just update the PL ;)

Comment: Using a PL function is certainly a possible solution, but I object to the word _need_ in your answer. You don’t _need_ to create such a function. There are pure SQL ways, as I’ve shown in my asnwer.

Comment: I agree with Dario, that's needlessly complex and will perform far worse than a recursive query

Comment: Noted and changed.